# How to load and display a image from a database mysql in a jsp page?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I need to show the information of the companies in my database with their logotype. I could already show the information (name, address and description) of my company table, but I do not know how to load the image saved in my database and show it on my jsp page.
This is my progress.

**companies class**

```
public class empresa {
    private int idEmpresa;
    private int fkpersona;    
    private String nombreE;
    private String direccion;
    private String rfc;
    private String texto;
    private InputStream archivoimg;
    private byte[] archivoimg2;}
```

**I do not put all the code of this class because it is very extensive and I only put the attributes of my class**

**DAO class:**

```
public List<empresa> MostrarEmpresa(){
        try{
        String sql="Select * From empresa Limit 6";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        List <empresa> lista = new LinkedList<>();
        empresa empre;
        while(rs.next()){
        empre = new empresa();
        empre.setIdEmpresa(rs.getInt("idempresa"));
        empre.setNombreE(rs.getString("nom_empresa"));
        empre.setDireccion(rs.getString("direccion"));
        empre.setRfc(rs.getString("rfc"));
        empre.setTexto(rs.getString("descrip"));
        lista.add(empre);
        }
        return lista;
        }catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**my servlet:**

```
public class InicioController extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher rd;
        conexion conn = new conexion();
        EmpresaDAO fun = new EmpresaDAO(conn);
        List<empresa> lista = new LinkedList<>();
        lista=fun.MostrarEmpresa("");
        conn.desconectar();
        request.setAttribute("empresas", lista);
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

**my jsp:**

```
<%@taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head></head>
<body>
<c:forEach items="${empresas}" var="empresa">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                            <a href="#portfolioModal${empresa.getIdEmpresa()}" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                                <div class="portfolio-hover">
                                    <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
       <img src="this is where I want to upload the image" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                            </a>
                            <div class="portfolio-caption">
                                <h4>${empresa.getNombreE()}</h4>
                                <p class="text-muted">${empresa.getDireccion()}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </c:forEach>
</body>
```

Comment: You can use another `url` (servlet/endpoint) for writing the bytes to the response and then have the img tag to read that url e.g. `<img src=myServlet?imageId=123></a>`

Comment: ok I need to learn what is endpoint and how to use it, thank you I will segre looking for information on the subject

Answer (score 0):

create image folder in side the Web Page folder and write the image and it file file project path seved by Database

after set img tag src"localhost:8080/projectname/" + databse saved url ("image/abc.jpg")

private String archivoimg;

empre.setArchivoimg(localhost:8080/projectname/" + databse saved url ("image/abc.jpg"));

Comment: I can not do that because the database server is not on my PC, I connect to the server that our teacher gave us to retrieve the information in the database. It is necessary to recover the image of the database that is in the companies table and in the column img with data type BLOB.
They asked us to recover the information of the companies (name, address, rfc and the logo that is the image), and I managed to recover the information of the companies and show it, but I have no idea how to recover the image of the database and Show it with your respective company information.